# Error in Broadcast Receiver launch

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, forceclose

I'm writing a simple code launch a broadcast receiver when I receive a message. But I get a force close error. I've added the required permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml . I took the code for BroadcastReceiever from this site(http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/). Please show me where I'm going wrong. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.findme;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        Object messages[] = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage smsMessage[] = new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < messages.length; n++) {
            smsMessage[n] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);*/
        Toast.makeText(context,"Reveived!",1).show();
        }

        // show first message
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Received SMS: " + smsMessage[0].getMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
```

Here is the logCat:

```
11-09 21:05:03.190: D/AndroidRuntime(446): Shutting down VM
11-09 21:05:03.190: W/dalvikvm(446): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.smsmanager1.receiver.SMSReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.smsmanager1.receiver.SMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.smsmanager1-1.apk]
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2789)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.smsmanager1.receiver.SMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.smsmanager1-1.apk]
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2780)
11-09 21:05:03.230: E/AndroidRuntime(446):  ... 10 more
11-09 21:05:13.211: I/Process(446): Sending signal. PID: 446 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class' fullname is incorrect in the declaration of the receiver.

In your manifest file, you must replace

```
com.example.smsmanager1.receiver.SMSReceiver
```

by

```
com.example.findme.SMSReceiver
```

Comment: This is even trickier to spot if your receiver is for BOOT_COMPLETED because you do not get the logCat